# Evaluating a value from two given equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x=\frac{4\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}$ and $y=\frac{2-2\lambda^2}{1+\lambda^2}$, where $\lambda$ is a real parameter and Z= $x^2$+$y^2$-xy, then what are the possible values of Z ?

How do I solve this problem? Are there any shortcuts or any theorems to be used?

I tried solving using a direct substitution, but could not proceed beyond step 2

$$ Z = x^2 + y^2 - xy$$ $$= (\frac{4\lambda}{1+\lambda^2})^2+ (\frac{2-2\lambda^2}{1+\lambda^2})^2 - (\frac{4\lambda}{1+\lambda^2})(\frac{2-2\lambda^2}{1+\lambda^2})$$  $$=\frac{4\lambda^4+8\lambda^3+8\lambda^2-8\lambda+4}{(1+\lambda^2)^2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $\lambda=\tan (t/2)$. Then $x=2\sin t$ and $y=2\cos t$,
so $x^2+y^2=4$. Also $xy=4\sin t\cos t=2\sin(2t)$. Which values can $4-2\sin 2t$ take?

Comment: So, 2 $\le$ Z $\le$ 6, am I right?

Comment: @RahnaKader That's right.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

WLOG $\lambda=\tan t$

$x=2\sin2t,y=2\cos2t$

Comment: See https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Answer (score 1):

The hint.

Let $\lambda=\tan\frac{t}{2}.$

Hence, $$Z=4(1-\sin{t}\cos{t})=4\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\sin2t\right)$$
and use $$-1\leq\sin2t\leq1.$$